# How does bwmorph branchpoints work?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I'm working on a piece of code in MATLAB using the Image Processing Toolbox, where I've used Skel=bwmorph(BM,'skel') to get a skeleton of a river. I want to use BP=bwmorph(Skel,'branchpoints') to get the points where confluences and tributaries exist. I'm getting a lot of false positives in BP whenever the skeleton looks like

```
oQo
Q
o
```

It marks the Q pixels as branch points as well, along with the actual, expected branch points. There are a lot of false positives like that.

I have noticed that a true branch point occours as an isolated pixel in BP, while fals branch points always form in pairs.

**Can anyone please tell me how the branchpoints algorithm finds the points?**
If I know that, I can be satisfied that there is an actual reason why the false positives are in pairs, and true positives are alone, rather than a lucky coincidence.

I have a feeling it looks at the 8-connectivity around the pixel, but I think that's not all it does.

To clarify, I've marked a cropped image of the output. The positives it gives are shown in red. As can be seen, just one of these pixels is actually a branch point. I want to know how the algorithm works so that I can give a logical reason for why false positives come in pairs (if they infact do).

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tg2j.jpg)

Comment: I don't get your drawing 'oQo Q o'. Can you maybe upload an image that shows what is happening?

Comment: I've added a link to the image: [link](http://i.imgur.com/w5udH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pixels are not minimally (8-)connected, try to use

```
Thin = bwmorph(Skel,'thin');
BP = bwmorph(Thin,'branchpoints');
```

to remove the unnecessary pixels. (You could also use thin instead of skel).

I think the basic algorithm of branchpoints looks at the 3,3 neighbourhood pixels if at least 3 pixels (excluding center) are '1'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using thin to minimally connect them gets rid of the false positives, _and_ I can see exactly why.

Additionally, I believe it doesn't just check the 3x3 neighbourhood, since otherwise, any T junction would give 4 pixels and not just 1. (At least that's how my replica of the algorithm panned out when I wrote it) However, you're right.. that does seem to be the main criterion.

Thanks again for the 'thin' operation...

Answer (score 2):

```
BW = (rgb2gray(imread('w5udH.jpg')) > 50);
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(BW), find(bwmorph(bwmorph(BW,'thin',Inf),'branchpoint') == 1));
imshow(BW); hold on; plot(j,i,'rx');
```

(there are some strange artifacts in the image caused by uploading it here)

[image]